# how to make UIScrollView not to show begin and end space

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I make a welcome controller with a scroll view in which there are four pages of images.
the scroll view only can be scrolled left or right, when I scroll it to the begin of the page,there is half white space, what also shows at the end of the page. I want to it not to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `storyboard`, select the `scrollview`, and deselect bounces horizontally in the attribute inspector (the shield in the right panel).  This also works for any `UIScrollView` subclass (`UITableView, UICollectionView`).